# "One may as well be hanged for a sheep as a lamb." What's 'as' here? 'rather than' looks better than 'as'

Tags: sentence-meaning, interpretation

> "One may as well be hanged for a sheep **as** a lamb."

What's 'as' here? 'rather than' looks better than 'as' because 'as' seems to be as 'like'.

What's the literal and/or real meaning of the sentence above?

Let's substitute A for 'a sheep' and B for 'a lamb'.

Does the sentence mean:

1. It's good to be killed for A rather than B
2. It's good to be killed for A as much as(to the same degree) B, i.e., no difference if killed for whether A or B

?

Comment: If you are going to be punished for a small crime (stealing a lamb) anyway, you might as well commit a larger one and steal a full-grown sheep. (Intended metaphorically, of course.)

Comment: ...from the days when stealing a sheep *was* a capital offence, see the so-called [Bloody Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody_Code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fuller version of the sentence would be

> One may as well be hanged for stealing a sheep as be hanged for stealing a lamb.

*As* does not mean "rather than"; it is a comparison, like *I'm as tall as my brother.*

Your second interpretation is correct: the sentence means something like
**If they are going to punish you the same way for a big crime and a small one, you might as well commit the big crime, not the small one.**